# Помогите составить запрос к бд mySQL

Tags: mysql

```html
CREATE TABLE `board` (
  `id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID Объявления',
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название Объявления',
  `country_id` int(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Страна',
  `city_id` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Город',
  `show_in_world` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Флаг, показывать по всему миру',
  `show_in_country` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Флаг, показывать по всей стране',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `board` VALUES
(100, 'Продам Daewoo', 1, 2, 0, 0),
(101, 'Продам Kia', 1, 2, 1, 0),
(102, 'Продам Ford', 1, 2, 0, 1);
```

Простыми словами должно получится как то так:

Если `show_in_world = 0`, тогда `(country_id = $country && city_id = $city)`, иначе конструкция `(country_id = $country && city_id = $city)` не прописывается.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0da6f6/5

Comment: Формулировка цели - ну совершенно невменяемая. Если трудно словами - попробуйте объяснить требуемым результатом для своего fiddle, что ли...

Answer (score 1):

Может, нужно

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       CASE WHEN show_in_world THEN country_id END country_id,
       CASE WHEN show_in_world THEN city_id END city_id
FROM board;
```

?